# CURL on Centos 7 getting NSS error -12188

Tags: curl, openssl, centos7

I've tried to send a `GET` request to a website running `HTTPS` but always getting `curl: (35) Peer reports it experienced an internal error.` and I get this error with this website only. When I tried to send a `GET` request to  Youtube, Google and other HTTPS sites, they work fine with my curl. Here is information in curl verbose mode on my server.

```
# curl -v https://***.vn > test.htm
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0*   
  Trying 103.x.x.x:443...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to ***.vn (103.x.x.x) port 443 (#0)
* Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb
*   CAfile: none
  CApath: none
* loaded libnssckbi.so
* NSS error -12188 (SSL_ERROR_INTERNAL_ERROR_ALERT)
* Peer reports it experienced an internal error.
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) Peer reports it experienced an internal error.
```

I have updated my server with `yum update` and updated curl to the latest version but still not work. After that, I tried to send a request from my Macbook, when read the result, I know my curl on my Mac using ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 ciphers as TSLv1.2 as well.

```
Viets-MacBook-Pro:~ vietnguyen$ curl -v https://*****.vn > test.htm
* Rebuilt URL to: https://*****.vn/
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0*   Trying 103.xx.xx.xx...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to *****.vn (103.xx.xx.xx) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* Cipher selection: ALL:!EXPORT:!EXPORT40:!EXPORT56:!aNULL:!LOW:!RC4:@STRENGTH
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/cert.pem
  CApath: none
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
} [217 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
{ [93 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
{ [3177 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
{ [300 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
{ [4 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
} [37 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
} [1 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
} [16 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
{ [1 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
{ [16 bytes data]
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
* ALPN, server did not agree to a protocol
* Server certificate:
*  subject: businessCategory=Private Organization; serialNumber=.....; CN=*****.vn
*  start date: Dec 11 06:22:40 2018 GMT
*  expire date: Dec 11 06:22:40 2020 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "*****.vn" matched cert's "*****.vn"
*  issuer: C=BE; O=GlobalSign nv-sa; CN=GlobalSign Extended Validation CA - SHA256 - G3
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: *****.vn
> User-Agent: curl/7.54.0
> Accept: */*
> 
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:01 --:--:--     0< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Cache-Control: private
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
< X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
< X-XSS-Protection: 1;mode=block
< Date: Thu, 20 Feb 2020 13:41:32 GMT
< Content-Length: 73711
< 
{ [7804 bytes data]
100 73711  100 73711    0     0  39172      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:-- 39166
* Connection #0 to host *****.vn left intact
```

But when I ran curl with selected ciphers on my webserver got error `Unknown cipher in list` then even I using the latest curl version and update my webserver as well.

```
[root@localhost vietnguyen]# curl --ciphers ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 -v https://*****.vn > test.htm
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0*   Trying 103.xx.xx.xx:443...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to *****.vn (103.xx.xx.xx) port 443 (#0)
* Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb
* Unknown cipher in list: ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
* Closing connection 0
curl: (59) Unknown cipher in list: ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
```

**My curl version**

```
# curl -V
curl 7.68.0 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.68.0 NSS/3.44 zlib/1.2.7 libpsl/0.7.0 (+libicu/50.1.2) libssh2/1.9.0 nghttp2/1.31.1
Release-Date: 2020-01-08
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtsp scp sftp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp 
Features: AsynchDNS GSS-API HTTP2 HTTPS-proxy IPv6 Kerberos Largefile libz Metalink NTLM NTLM_WB PSL SPNEGO SSL UnixSockets
```

I also run `yum update nss nss-util nss-sysinit nss-tools` to the latest nss version still not make it works.

**My openssl version**

```
# openssl version
OpenSSL 1.1.1d  10 Sep 2019
```

Can anyone has any idea to fix this?

Comment: Your OpenSSL version doesn't matter; your curl on CentOS is using NSS not OpenSSL. For NSS the spelling of ciphersuite names is different, see the NSS section of [this doc page](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/ssl-ciphers.html); you want `ecdhe_rsa_aes_256_gcm_sha_384`. You could also check `openssl s_client -connect $host:443`

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 thank you for your help, but do you have any way to fix my problem? My curl only fail when send request to this website and I searching every where but cannot find any solution

Comment: Where did this curl build come from? The (only) one in the CentOS7 repo is 7.29 according to my test system [and rpmfind](http://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=curl&submit=Search+...&system=centos&arch=) If that doesn't give a clue I would ask the server what it thinks the problem is, or if that isn't available get a network trace and look at it, possibly in comparison to a successful one from the other client (Mac) or openssl if that works, although I've looked at enough TLS traces I often don't need a comparison.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 I just install CURL from yum, could you test a get request by curl to https://vietlott.vn on your test system?

Answer (score 1):

First: I have on CentOS 7 (after updating)

```
$ curl -V
curl 7.29.0 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.29.0 NSS/3.44 zlib/1.2.7 libidn/1.28 libssh2/1.8.0
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtsp scp sftp smtp smtps telnet tftp
Features: AsynchDNS GSS-Negotiate IDN IPv6 Largefile NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz unix-sockets
$ openssl version
OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017
$ yum list curl nss openssl 
[snip]
Installed Packages
curl.x86_64                       7.29.0-54.el7_7.2                    @updates
nss.x86_64                        3.44.0-7.el7_7                       @updates
openssl.x86_64                    1:1.0.2k-19.el7                      @anaconda
Available Packages
nss.i686                          3.44.0-7.el7_7                       updates
$ yum repolist
[snip]
repo id                             repo name                             status
base/7/x86_64                       CentOS-7 - Base                       10,097
extras/7/x86_64                     CentOS-7 - Extras                        335
updates/7/x86_64                    CentOS-7 - Updates                     1,774
repolist: 12,206
```

all of which agree with rpmfind except it has nss at -4 -- not curl 7.68 or OpenSSL 1.1.1d. Please check what yum says you have installed, and from what repo (the righthand column).

Anyway, my version of curl/NSS **does get the same error** on that server. Capturing and decoding with wireshark it looks like a reasonable TLS1.2 ClientHello. My OpenSSL 1.0.2k (with whatever patches RH/CentOS adds) `s_client` succeeds (as long as I specify `-servername` which is now widely required but was not default in 1.0.2), and so do OpenSSL source builds I have on another system for various 1.0.2, 1.1.0 (same servername), and 1.1.1 (servername is now default). Since wget (which is available for CentOS7) uses OpenSSL, **wget succeeds**, and provides essentially the same functionality as curl.

After some experimenting (with Java) it appears this server fails on an otherwise-valid TLS1.2 hello that uses the *extension* for rfc5746 (which NSS does), but succeeds if using the SCSV (which OpenSSL does). This is rather bad of it, since the rfc clearly requires server support for both. However, unless you have some influence with the developers of the software or middleware used on the server, you probably can't do anything about this and will need a workaround such as wget.

It appears NSS has been using the extension instead of SCSV [since 2013](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=549042)

Even odder, Firefox uses NSS (though I can't find a way to tell which version) and my current 68esr sends a *TLS1.3* ClientHello with the renegotiation extension (not SCSV) and succeeds. It may be that the server is checking protocol version first, and then handling rfc5746 differently (avoiding the failure) or not at all, because TLS1.3 forbids renegotiation entirely making rfc5746 moot.

Comment: Thank you for your work, sory but my english is not very well to understand your answer 100% but all you trying to say is I must use wget instead of CURL?

Comment: I'm saying wget works and is simple to substitute. There are other ways that have at least some chance of working, but none as simple.

Comment: Sorry for my late reply but I like to fix CURL because I will use PHP to build my own tools. Anyway, thanks for your time.

Comment: I don't believe you can get curl using NSS to work unless you build (and then maintain) your own modified NSS. However, it should work if you (re)build curl from source to use OpenSSL and _not_ NSS. You'll have to rebuild PHP to use that libcurl, of course. Have fun.

Comment: Thanks for your times again. I will give it a try